# ORA-00604 (error occurred at recursive SQL level string) hides the real error

Tags: trigger, oracle-12c, database-link

My multithreaded program inserts records into a table. `ORA-00001` (unique constraint violated) should not be fatal.

But prod environment has a complex configuration with read-only schema and the table for my inserts being a `synonym` for a remote table, which is partitioned.

Inserts work fine until PK violated, then instead of `SQLCODE=-1` I'm getting `SQLCODE=-614` and a multiline description:

```
insert into CDRGPRSIMEI (ms_id,startdatetime,calltype,imei) values (:b0,to_date(:b1,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS'),:b2,:b3)
^
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access
ORA-06512: at line 120
ORA-16000: database open for read-only access
ORA-00001: unique constraint (CDRIMEI.PK_CDRGPRSIMEI) violated
ORA-02063: preceding line from CDRIMEI_PRIM_PPB
```

What can cause this? Is it always related to triggers? If DBA can't fix it on prod, how to reproduce this on my test env. (e.g. by writing a special trigger)?